# how to prevent stop fish to reverse randomly and it happen at more than one fish

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In this code the fish is created randomly with unique id `fish1`, `fish2`, etc.. and if I create more than one fish then the fishes are going reverse randomly.

I think the problem is with the `if` condition and I've tried a lot. Can any one suggest a solution?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
var newfishid = 1;
$('.post-button').on("click", function(e) {
    var row = "";
    row = "<div class='large-fish fish' id='fish" + newfishid + "'>";
    row += "<input type='button' value='Click me to view the problem' class='fish-hover-box' />";
    row += " </div>"
    $('#container').append(row);
    newfishid++;
    $('.fish').on("mouseenter", function(e) {
        $(this).addClass("HoverFish");
        $(this).stop(true);
    }).on("mouseleave", function(){
        $(this).removeClass("HoverFish");
        AnimateFish();
    });        
    $('#categories-select').hide();
    AnimateFish();
});

function AnimateFish() {
    var Fish3 = $("[id^=fish]").not(".HoverFish"),
        theContainer = $("#container"),
        maxLeft = theContainer.width() - Fish3.width() - 50,
        maxTop = theContainer.height() - Fish3.height(),
        leftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxLeft),
        topPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxTop) + 100,
        imgRight = "Assets/fish-glow3-right.gif",
        imgLeft = "Assets/fish-glow3.gif";
    if ($("[id^=fish]").position().left >= leftPos) {
        $(this).css("background-image", 'url("' + imgRight + '")');
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-image", 'url("' + imgLeft + '")');
    }
    Fish3.animate({
        "left": leftPos,
        "top": topPos
    }, 1800, AnimateFish);
}
```

Comment: I'll come back and add a bounty if you haven't found a solution to this. I may have to do some edits to the question to try and limit the problem and make it easier to answer, though

Comment: yeah dude, still now i din get ans:(

Comment: I understand. It has to be 48 hours without answer for me to add a bounty to this. After that you should get an answer

Comment: Your description of the problem is a bit vague. It would help if you described more clearly 1) what behavior you want, 2) what behavior you're getting. Even better if you can make a JSFiddle showing the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem you have, is that everytime you access fishes with jQuery, you're accessing all of them:

- `$('.fish').on` you're bind event on all the fishes (that means multiple times for the previously created fishes)
- `Fish3 = $("[id^=fish]").not(".HoverFish")` and `Fish3.animate` You're updating the animation of all the fishes each time `AnimateFish` is called. (Each time the animation of one fish finishes, the animation of all fishes are updated)
- `$("[id^=fish]").position().left` You're updating the css of the fish according to the position of the first fish found in DOM (first created fish), not of the current fish.

I did some cleanup in your code to handle each fish independently:

```
var newfishid = 1;
var $container = $('#container');
$('.post-button').on("click", function(e) {
    var fishHtml = "<div class='large-fish fish fa' id='fish" + newfishid + "'>";
    //fishHtml += "<input type='button' value='Click me to view the problem' class='fish-hover-box' />";
    fishHtml += " </div>";
    var $fish = $(fishHtml).appendTo($container);
    newfishid++;
    $fish.on("mouseenter", function(e) {
        $(this).addClass("HoverFish");
        updateFishAnimation($fish);
    }).on("mouseleave", function(){
        $(this).removeClass("HoverFish");
        updateFishAnimation($fish);
    });
    $('#categories-select').hide();
    updateFishAnimation($fish);
});

function updateFishAnimation($fish) {
    $fish.stop();
    if($fish.hasClass('HoverFish')) {
        return;
    }
    var maxLeft = $container.width() - $fish.width() - 50,
        maxTop = $container.height() - $fish.height(),
        leftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxLeft),
        topPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxTop) + 100,
        imgRight = "Assets/fish-glow3-right.gif",
        imgLeft = "Assets/fish-glow3.gif";
    if ($fish.position().left >= leftPos) {
        //PUT WHAT YOU NEED $fish.addClass('fa-arrow-left').removeClass('fa-arrow-right');
    } else {
        //PUT WHAT YOU NEED $fish.addClass('fa-arrow-right').removeClass('fa-arrow-left');
    }
    $fish.animate({
        "left": leftPos,
        "top": topPos
    }, 1800, $.proxy(updateFishAnimation, null, $fish));
}
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/s44sv87t/1/)

Comment: :) thanks for answering. the fiddle looks good. I'll award the bounty as soon as I am able to. The OP should be able to solve the issue with the information provded